# Convert populated Set<String> to [String] in swift

Tags: string, swift, setstring

I am kind stuck with the following.

I've got the following array

```
var selectedItems = Set<String>()
```

That has some items from parse inserted to it

```
self.selectedItems.insert(objectToAppend)
```

Then I've created the following variable where I intend to convert the Set into something I could use on my parse query with the following line. But almost nothing converts. `[AnyObject, [String], [self.selectedHobbies], ["\(self.selectedHobbies)"]` ... none works.

```
let itemsArray = self.selectedHobbies as [AnyObject]
```

And if I do not convert it I cannot use in the query bellow.

```
query.whereKey("itemTag", containedIn: itemsArray as [AnyObject])
```

If I could manage to convert it to a `[String]` it would solve my problem. Not sure how.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046695/swift-1-2-set-to-array ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When in doubt, try the init!

```
let selectedItems: Set<String> = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
let arr = [String](selectedItems)
```