# Fetch Data from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm getting data from core data and saving it inside an array. This array is collection of dictionary. However there are duplicate dictionary inside the array. How do I filter these duplicate dictionaries inside the nsarray in Swift?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Show the log of array that will more helpful.

Comment: why is it an array of dictionaries? show the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of duplicate dictionaries you can try a counter variable.  Then a simple 'if' statement i.e. if counter == 1 { //do something }

Answer (score 0):

### How do I filter these duplicate dictionaries inside the nsarray in Swift?

Old way from ObjC still works with Swift ~ You take advantage of the properties of a set. Add the values you want into a Set. You can use the contains method to verify whether the key exists before adding it to the set. Since a Set can only contain unique values it will filter the duplicates. When finished check out the allobjects on the Set object.

A second option would be to use either the map or the filter function on the array with some comparative logic or some other criterion to define uniqueness (I don't know your precise data set so it's hard to give a relevant sample but generally you can see this article on [UseYourLoaf](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/)). If you are using Swift 2.2+ you can try the forEach function available on the collections.

**Other References:**

Search SO for keywords Swift Set

Search SO for keywords Swift Array

[Swift Set To Array On SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046695/swift-set-to-array)

[Swift Collection Types on Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

[Swift Official Documentation Book from Swift.org](https://swift.org/documentation/TheSwiftProgrammingLanguage(Swift3).epub)